# Can CouchDB do this?

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I evaluating CouchDB & I'm wondering whether it's possible to achieve the following functionality.

I'm planning to develop a web application and the app should allow a 'parent' table and derivatives of this table. The parent table will contains all the fields (master table) and the user will selectively choose fields, which should be saved as separate tables.

My queries are as follows:

1. Is it possible to save different versions of the same table using CouchDB?
2. Is there an alternative to creating child tables (and clutter the database)?

I'm new to NoSQL databases and am evaluating CouchDB because it supports JSON out of the box and this format seems to fit the application very well.

If there are alternatives to NOT save the derivatives as separate tables, the better will the application be. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of relationship do you have between the parent and child tables? Is that a one-one, one-many? Note that couchdb is a document oriented database. There are no tables only documents.

Comment: Hi  randominstanceOfLivingThing,

The relationship is one-to-many. The user will edit the parent document from the front end and should be able to save the edits as separate documents. So, I the relationship is 1:many. The user will subsequently edit the child document to create derivatives and so on.

I'm getting started with CouchDB, so please excuse me if my queries are very basic.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB is a [document oriented database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) which means you cannot talk in terms of tables. There are only documents. The _rev (or revision ID) describes a version of a [document](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/documents.html).

[In CouchDB, there are 2 ways to achieve relationships](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EntityRelationship).

1. Use separate documents
2. Use an embedded array

If you do not prefer to clutter your database, you can choose to use option (2) by using an embedded array.
This gives you the ability to have cascade delete functionality as well for free.

Comment: I think I'll explore the pointers you shared,  randominstanceOfLivingThing. Thanks a ton! Really appreciate it!